# Problemas de paginação utilizando WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, paginação

Fala pessoal, tudo bacana? Estou tendo problemas com a paginação do WP nas páginas de categorias do site que estou desenvolvendo. Suponhamos que eu queira exibir 06 posts por página, certo? Mas ao invés do site exibir 06 posts diferentes a cada página, é exibido os mesmos posts em várias páginas.

Alguém teve problema semelhante e conseguiu resolver? Logo abaixo, compartilho o código que estou utilizando.

```
<!-- Global Page Section Start -->
<section class="global-page-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="block">
                    <h2><?php the_category(''); ?></h2>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php">
                                <i class="ion-ios-home"></i>
                                <?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ol><!-- .breadcrumb -->

                    <div class="box-voltar">
                        <a href="javascript:history.back()" title="Voltar à Página Anterior" class="button-voltar"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Voltar</a>
                    </div><!-- .box-voltar -->
                </div><!-- .block -->
            </div><!-- .col-lg-12 -->
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container -->  
</section><!--.global-page-header-->



<section class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 conteudo-interno">
                <?php
                //the arguments for loop
                $args = array(
                    'category_name'  => 'servicos',
                    'orderby'        => 'title',
                    'order'          => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => '1'
                ); 

                //the query
                $posts_servicos = new WP_Query($args); ?>

                <?php if ( $posts_servicos->have_posts()) : ?>

                <!-- the loop -->
                <?php while ( $posts_servicos->have_posts()) : $posts_servicos->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="box-post text-center">
                            <div class="imagem-redonda">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php 
                                        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                                            the_post_thumbnail('images');
                                        }else{
                                            echo '<img alt="<?the_title();?>" src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/default.png" />';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                            </div><!--.imagem-redonda-->

                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Ler Mais">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs button-category">Saiba Mais</button>
                            </a>
                        </div><!--.box-post-->
                    </div><!-- .col-lg-4 -->

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- end of the loop -->

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <p><?php _e('<h1>Desculpe!</h1><p>Nenhum conteúdo cadastrado!</p>');?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div class="pagination">
                    <?php post_pagination(); ?>
                </div><!--.pagination-->

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><!-- .col-lg-12 .conteudo-interno-->
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</section><!-- .main -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Não está funcionando corretamente porque você esqueceu de informar o parâmetro `paged`. Esse parâmetro diz em qual página você está, como ele não é informado, em todas as páginas ele vai mostrar os dados da primeira.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'category_name'  => 'servicos',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'paged'          => $paged
);
```

Comment: Fala Kayo! Rapaz, fiz um teste e funcionou perfitamente. Agradecido.

Comment: Que bom que minha resposta lhe ajudou @rafaelpimentao se possível marca como melhor resposta.